# IF clause in SQL from statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

I need a temporary solution to a problem I've created.  Essentially I want to calculate two values, but use a different method dependant on the result of a condition.

```sql
select userReturnval, userregisterid, OtherValue
FROM
(
   (SELECT otherValue
   FROM...
   ) as tblO  --unrelated table
  ,

  ( 
    if (select count(userregisterid) from table1 where site =@siteID and userid=@userID) >0
      SELECT userReturnval, userregisterid
    FROM
    (
     SELECT userReturnval, userregisterid, Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY .. ORDER BY       ...) as RANK
            FROM ...
            WHERE --first where clause
        ) as tblRank
        WHERE (RANK =1)
    else
      SELECT userReturnval, userregisterid
      FROM
        (
     SELECT userReturnval, userregisterid, Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY .. ORDER BY       ...) as RANK
            FROM ...
            WHERE --different where clause
        ) as tblRank
        WHERE (RANK =1)

  ) as tblR
```

My if works fine on its own, I just to get it working as part of the larger query.  At the moment, sqlserver doesn't like the if being in there.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction!

Comment: I assume this is not a single query that you are executing. Please confirm that it's T-SQL in a stored procedure?

Comment: Yes, it is.  I'm bringing back a helper object containing a number of separate values taken from the DB.  There are no joins between the separately calculated tables.

Comment: "doesn't like" means what? Any error messages or just unexpected behavior? A little bit more detail please.

Comment: I think you need first to fill the temporary tables (table variables) using your conditions, and then select from these tables.

Comment: Sorry.   I'm getting the error message 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'.  The if statement line reads, if (select count(registerid) from table1 where site =@siteID and userid=@userID) > 0

Comment: The whole if statement returns fine if it is calculated on its own.

Comment: Where do `userReturnval` & `userregisterid` come from and how is the IF action supposed to differ from the ELSE one?

Comment: Ok, I've edited the post.  The second differs only in the where clause.  The whole if statement will calculate and return fine if in a query on its own.  It seems that it doesn't like SELECT FROM (if

Comment: "FROM ... " reffer to the same table in two subqueries of IF ELSE ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using case statements in the WHERE clause, something like the statement below. Note that I don't think this will be particularly optimal for performance.

Doing it like this does allow you to keep it to a single statement though:

```
select userReturnval, userregisterid, OtherValue
FROM
(
   (SELECT otherValue
   FROM...
   ) as tblO  --unrelated table
  ,

  ( 
    SELECT userReturnval, userregisterid
    FROM
    (
     SELECT userReturnval, userregisterid, Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY .. ORDER BY       ...) as RANK
            FROM ...
            WHERE 
                case --Choose which where clause to use
                    when (select count(userregisterid) from table1 where site =@siteID and userid=@userID) >0 then 
                        case when /*First where clause*/ then 1
                        else 0
                        end
                    else
                        case when /*Second where clause*/ then 1
                        else 0
                        end
                    end
                 = 1                
        ) as tblRank
        WHERE (RANK =1)
  ) as tblR
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is the way to do it.  Obviously, this is only a temporary measure - I'm not able to patch for a couple of weeks yet otherwise I would be creating new procedures and calling them.  Thanks again!